# Path matching inside a VALUES clause

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to perform path matching inside a VALUES clause in sparql in order to match all instances *and* subclasses of both battles and sieges in wikidata. The following request repeatedly [times out](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fbattle%20%3FbattleLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Ftype%20%7Bwd%3AQ178561%20wd%3AQ188055%7D%20%3Fbattle%20%28wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%29%20%3Ftype%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fbattle%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FqueryByTitle.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28REGEX%28%3FqueryByTitle%2C%20%22saratoga%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7D).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?battle ?battleLabel WHERE {
  {
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
    VALUES ?type {wd:Q178561 wd:Q188055} ?battle (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) ?type .
    ?battle rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
    FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "saratoga", "i"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `UNION` instead of `VALUES`; or `SELECT DISTINCT ?battle WHERE {
   hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
   VALUES ?type {wd:Q178561 wd:Q188055} 
   ?subtype wdt:P279* ?type . ?battle wdt:P31 ?subtype . 
   ?battle rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
   FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "saratoga", "i")) SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: @StanislavKralin thanks, your solution works. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `VALUES`, esp. in conjunction with `/`, confuses the Blazegraph's query optimizer in that case.

Use `UNION` instead of `VALUES`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?battle ?battleLabel WHERE {
    { ?battle wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q178561 }
    UNION
    { ?battle wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q188055 }
    ?battle rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
    FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "saratoga", "i"))
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

Alternatively, disable the optimizer and specify explicit order:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?battle ?battleLabel WHERE {
    hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
    VALUES ?type {wd:Q178561 wd:Q188055}
    ?subtype wdt:P279* ?type .
    ?battle wdt:P31 ?subtype .
    ?battle rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
    FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "saratoga", "i"))
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```